# Triangular numbers in python adding a range

Tags: python, math, python-2.7, python-3.x, discrete-mathematics

I am struggling with what I know should be a really simple loop. I need to add all the numbers from 0 to n. The end result needs to be a positive integer, though I know if it comes out negative I can just get the absolute value to evaluate it to positive.

```
ex: n = 5 
    sum = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
    sum = 15
```

what I have so far is this

```
def triangular(n):
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(n):
        sum_-= n
    return sum_
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't indicated what your problem or question is. And why are you doing subtraction instead of addition?

Comment: If you want to compute the sum, 1.) why would expect the sum of positive integers to be negative? 2.) why do you have `sum_ -= n`. Shouldn't it be `sum_ += i`? 3.) There is a `sum` function, e.g. `sum(range(5)) = 15`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't it just be?

```
def triangular(n):
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(n+1):
        sum_+= i
    return sum_
```

This will add all numbers from 0 to n.  Though this could be put into one line:

```
def triangular(n):
    return sum(range(n+1))
```

Answer (score 7):

The sum of numbers from 0 to N is N(N+1)/2.  How about:

```
return n * (n+1) / 2
```

rather than using a loop?

Comment: This is obviously the right thing to do in real-life code, but for a novice trying to understand how to translate an English-language algorithm into a Python loop it isn't very helpful.

Comment: @abarnert Sorry you din't find my response helpful.  The question didn't seem to have trouble with Python looping syntax, but rather adding the numbers up.  As you said, this solution might be preferred in "real-life" code since it accomplishes the goal with just a few operations.

Comment: "This is obviously the right thing to do in real-life code, but…" doesn't mean it isn't helpful; it means it's _is_ helpful, being it's obviously the right thing to do in real-life code and all. Don't be so defensive.